# Creating a scrollable dialog

Tags: winapi, scroll, dialog, atl, wtl

I was wondering if there's an accepted strategy for creating a scrollable dialog in the Windows API, perhaps using the WTL scrollable classes (`CScrollImpl`, `CScrollWindowImpl`, `CScrollContainer`, etc.).

One idea I had was to place an inner child dialog (which contains the actual controls) within an outer parent window, and then simply move the child dialog window in response to the scroll bar messages.  That way, at least in my mind, you wouldn't have to move each individual control when scrolling occurs.  You'd just move the inner window, which would in turn move the controls.

But maybe I'm thinking about this all wrong.  Has anybody dealt with this problem before?  Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's essentially what MFC's [CFormView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cformview-class) does. Though, what's your question?

Comment: Thanks, although I'm not working within an MFC project. I guess my question is what the typical approach is for creating a scrollable dialog.  Moving all the controls collectively?  Using the child dialog approach?

Comment: The system doesn't provide an implementation, so you're going to have to go with a custom solution. Whether it is the typical approach or not, following MFC certainly ensures that you it's tried and tested, by hundreds and thousands of application, over the course of several decades.

Comment: Believe me, I have no desire to reinvent the wheel.  I was just hoping to avoid a dependency on MFC and stick with ATL/WTL instead.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting that you use MFC. You were asking about a particular implementation strategy and whether it were sound. And the answer to that question is that, yes, this is a possible approach, and a common library uses it successfully. How to translate that into the particular windowing library you chose is something you will have to work out.

Comment: @user15025873 Do you want the scrolling in a view (like the form-view) or a normal dialog with scrollable contents?

Answer (score 0):

This is the modified version, which works in dialogs:

```cpp
template <class T>
class CScroller
{
public:
    enum { uSCROLL_FLAGS = SW_INVALIDATE };

    POINT m_ptOffset;
    SIZE m_sizeAll;
    SIZE m_sizeLine;
    SIZE m_sizePage;
    SIZE m_sizeClient;
    int m_zDelta;              // current wheel value
    int m_nWheelLines;         // number of lines to scroll on wheel
    int m_zHDelta;              // current horizontal wheel value
    int m_nHWheelChars;         // number of chars to scroll on horizontal wheel
    UINT m_uScrollFlags;
    DWORD m_dwExtendedStyle;   // scroll specific extended styles

// Constructor
    CScroller() : m_zDelta(0), m_nWheelLines(3),
        m_zHDelta(0), m_nHWheelChars(3),
        m_uScrollFlags(0U), m_dwExtendedStyle(0)
    {
        m_ptOffset.x = 0;
        m_ptOffset.y = 0;
        m_sizeAll.cx = 0;
        m_sizeAll.cy = 0;
        m_sizePage.cx = 0;
        m_sizePage.cy = 0;
        m_sizeLine.cx = 0;
        m_sizeLine.cy = 0;
        m_sizeClient.cx = 0;
        m_sizeClient.cy = 0;

        SetScrollExtendedStyle(SCRL_SCROLLCHILDREN | SCRL_ERASEBACKGROUND);
    }

    // Attributes & Operations
    DWORD GetScrollExtendedStyle() const
    {
        return m_dwExtendedStyle;
    }

    DWORD SetScrollExtendedStyle(DWORD dwExtendedStyle, DWORD dwMask = 0)
    {
        DWORD dwPrevStyle = m_dwExtendedStyle;
        if (dwMask == 0)
            m_dwExtendedStyle = dwExtendedStyle;
        else
            m_dwExtendedStyle = (m_dwExtendedStyle & ~dwMask) | (dwExtendedStyle & dwMask);
        // cache scroll flags
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        (void)pT;   // avoid level 4 warning
        m_uScrollFlags = pT->uSCROLL_FLAGS | (IsScrollingChildren() ? SW_SCROLLCHILDREN : 0) | (IsErasingBackground() ? SW_ERASE : 0);
        m_uScrollFlags |= (IsSmoothScroll() ? SW_SMOOTHSCROLL : 0);
        return dwPrevStyle;
    }

    // offset operations
    void SetScrollOffset(int x, int y, BOOL bRedraw = TRUE)
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));

        pT->AdjustScrollOffset(x, y);

        int dx = m_ptOffset.x - x;
        int dy = m_ptOffset.y - y;
        m_ptOffset.x = x;
        m_ptOffset.y = y;

        // block: set horizontal scroll bar
        {
            SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO) };
            si.fMask = SIF_POS;
            if ((m_dwExtendedStyle & SCRL_DISABLENOSCROLLH) != 0)
                si.fMask |= SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL;
            si.nPos = m_ptOffset.x;
            pT->SetScrollInfo(SB_HORZ, &si, bRedraw);
        }

        // block: set vertical scroll bar
        {
            SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO) };
            si.fMask = SIF_POS;
            if ((m_dwExtendedStyle & SCRL_DISABLENOSCROLLV) != 0)
                si.fMask |= SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL;
            si.nPos = m_ptOffset.y;
            pT->SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &si, bRedraw);
        }

        // Move all children if needed
        if (IsScrollingChildren() && ((dx != 0) || (dy != 0)))
        {
            for (HWND hWndChild = ::GetWindow(pT->m_hWnd, GW_CHILD); hWndChild != NULL; hWndChild = ::GetWindow(hWndChild, GW_HWNDNEXT))
            {
                RECT rect = {};
                ::GetWindowRect(hWndChild, &rect);
                ::MapWindowPoints(NULL, pT->m_hWnd, (LPPOINT)&rect, 1);
                ::SetWindowPos(hWndChild, NULL, rect.left + dx, rect.top + dy, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
            }
        }

        if (bRedraw)
            pT->Invalidate();
    }

    void SetScrollOffset(POINT ptOffset, BOOL bRedraw = TRUE)
    {
        SetScrollOffset(ptOffset.x, ptOffset.y, bRedraw);
    }

    void GetScrollOffset(POINT& ptOffset) const
    {
        ptOffset = m_ptOffset;
    }

    // size operations
    void SetScrollSize(int cx, int cy, BOOL bRedraw = TRUE, bool bResetOffset = true)
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));

        m_sizeAll.cx = cx;
        m_sizeAll.cy = cy;

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        if (!bResetOffset)
        {
            x = m_ptOffset.x;
            y = m_ptOffset.y;
            pT->AdjustScrollOffset(x, y);
        }

        int dx = m_ptOffset.x - x;
        int dy = m_ptOffset.y - y;
        m_ptOffset.x = x;
        m_ptOffset.y = y;

        // block: set horizontal scroll bar
        {
            SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO) };
            si.fMask = SIF_PAGE | SIF_RANGE | SIF_POS;
            if ((m_dwExtendedStyle & SCRL_DISABLENOSCROLLH) != 0)
                si.fMask |= SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL;
            si.nMin = 0;
            si.nMax = m_sizeAll.cx - 1;
            si.nPage = m_sizeClient.cx;
            si.nPos = m_ptOffset.x;
            pT->SetScrollInfo(SB_HORZ, &si, bRedraw);
        }

        // block: set vertical scroll bar
        {
            SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO) };
            si.fMask = SIF_PAGE | SIF_RANGE | SIF_POS;
            if ((m_dwExtendedStyle & SCRL_DISABLENOSCROLLV) != 0)
                si.fMask |= SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL;
            si.nMin = 0;
            si.nMax = m_sizeAll.cy - 1;
            si.nPage = m_sizeClient.cy;
            si.nPos = m_ptOffset.y;
            pT->SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &si, bRedraw);
        }

        // Move all children if needed
        if (IsScrollingChildren() && ((dx != 0) || (dy != 0)))
        {
            for (HWND hWndChild = ::GetWindow(pT->m_hWnd, GW_CHILD); hWndChild != NULL; hWndChild = ::GetWindow(hWndChild, GW_HWNDNEXT))
            {
                RECT rect = {};
                ::GetWindowRect(hWndChild, &rect);
                ::MapWindowPoints(NULL, pT->m_hWnd, (LPPOINT)&rect, 1);
                ::SetWindowPos(hWndChild, NULL, rect.left + dx, rect.top + dy, 0, 0, SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
            }
        }

        SetScrollLine(0, 0);
        SetScrollPage(0, 0);

        if (bRedraw)
            pT->Invalidate();
    }

    void SetScrollSize(SIZE size, BOOL bRedraw = TRUE, bool bResetOffset = true)
    {
        SetScrollSize(size.cx, size.cy, bRedraw, bResetOffset);
    }

    void GetScrollSize(SIZE& sizeWnd) const
    {
        sizeWnd = m_sizeAll;
    }

    // line operations
    void SetScrollLine(int cxLine, int cyLine)
    {
        ATLASSERT((cxLine >= 0) && (cyLine >= 0));
        ATLASSERT((m_sizeAll.cx != 0) && (m_sizeAll.cy != 0));

        m_sizeLine.cx = T::CalcLineOrPage(cxLine, m_sizeAll.cx, 100);
        m_sizeLine.cy = T::CalcLineOrPage(cyLine, m_sizeAll.cy, 100);
    }

    void SetScrollLine(SIZE sizeLine)
    {
        SetScrollLine(sizeLine.cx, sizeLine.cy);
    }

    void GetScrollLine(SIZE& sizeLine) const
    {
        sizeLine = m_sizeLine;
    }

    // page operations
    void SetScrollPage(int cxPage, int cyPage)
    {
        ATLASSERT((cxPage >= 0) && (cyPage >= 0));
        ATLASSERT((m_sizeAll.cx != 0) && (m_sizeAll.cy != 0));

        m_sizePage.cx = T::CalcLineOrPage(cxPage, m_sizeAll.cx, 10);
        m_sizePage.cy = T::CalcLineOrPage(cyPage, m_sizeAll.cy, 10);
    }

    void SetScrollPage(SIZE sizePage)
    {
        SetScrollPage(sizePage.cx, sizePage.cy);
    }

    void GetScrollPage(SIZE& sizePage) const
    {
        sizePage = m_sizePage;
    }

    // commands
    void ScrollLineDown()
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_VERT, SB_LINEDOWN, (int&)m_ptOffset.y, m_sizeAll.cy, m_sizePage.cy, m_sizeLine.cy);
    }

    void ScrollLineUp()
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_VERT, SB_LINEUP, (int&)m_ptOffset.y, m_sizeAll.cy, m_sizePage.cy, m_sizeLine.cy);
    }

    void ScrollPageDown()
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_VERT, SB_PAGEDOWN, (int&)m_ptOffset.y, m_sizeAll.cy, m_sizePage.cy, m_sizeLine.cy);
    }

    void ScrollPageUp()
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_VERT, SB_PAGEUP, (int&)m_ptOffset.y, m_sizeAll.cy, m_sizePage.cy, m_sizeLine.cy);
    }

    void ScrollTop()
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_VERT, SB_TOP, (int&)m_ptOffset.y, m_sizeAll.cy, m_sizePage.cy, m_sizeLine.cy);
    }

    void ScrollBottom()
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_VERT, SB_BOTTOM, (int&)m_ptOffset.y, m_sizeAll.cy, m_sizePage.cy, m_sizeLine.cy);
    }

    void ScrollLineRight()
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_HORZ, SB_LINEDOWN, (int&)m_ptOffset.x, m_sizeAll.cx, m_sizePage.cx, m_sizeLine.cx);
    }

    void ScrollLineLeft()
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_HORZ, SB_LINEUP, (int&)m_ptOffset.x, m_sizeAll.cx, m_sizePage.cx, m_sizeLine.cx);
    }

    void ScrollPageRight()
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_HORZ, SB_PAGEDOWN, (int&)m_ptOffset.x, m_sizeAll.cx, m_sizePage.cx, m_sizeLine.cx);
    }

    void ScrollPageLeft()
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_HORZ, SB_PAGEUP, (int&)m_ptOffset.x, m_sizeAll.cx, m_sizePage.cx, m_sizeLine.cx);
    }

    void ScrollAllLeft()
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_HORZ, SB_TOP, (int&)m_ptOffset.x, m_sizeAll.cx, m_sizePage.cx, m_sizeLine.cx);
    }

    void ScrollAllRight()
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_HORZ, SB_BOTTOM, (int&)m_ptOffset.x, m_sizeAll.cx, m_sizePage.cx, m_sizeLine.cx);
    }

    // scroll to make point/view/window visible
    void ScrollToView(POINT pt)
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        RECT rect = { pt.x, pt.y, pt.x, pt.y };
        pT->ScrollToView(rect);
    }

    void ScrollToView(RECT& rect)
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));

        RECT rcClient = {};
        pT->GetClientRect(&rcClient);

        int x = m_ptOffset.x;
        if (rect.left < m_ptOffset.x)
            x = rect.left;
        else if (rect.right > (m_ptOffset.x + rcClient.right))
            x = rect.right - rcClient.right;

        int y = m_ptOffset.y;
        if (rect.top < m_ptOffset.y)
            y = rect.top;
        else if (rect.bottom > (m_ptOffset.y + rcClient.bottom))
            y = rect.bottom - rcClient.bottom;

        SetScrollOffset(x, y);
    }

    void ScrollToView(HWND hWnd)
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));

        RECT rect = {};
        ::GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
        ::OffsetRect(&rect, m_ptOffset.x, m_ptOffset.y);
        ::MapWindowPoints(NULL, pT->m_hWnd, (LPPOINT)&rect, 2);
        ScrollToView(rect);
    }

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CScroller)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CREATE, OnCreate)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_VSCROLL, OnVScroll)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_HSCROLL, OnHScroll)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_MOUSEWHEEL, OnMouseWheel)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_MOUSEHWHEEL, OnMouseHWheel)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_SETTINGCHANGE, OnSettingChange)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_SIZE, OnSize)
        // standard scroll commands
        ALT_MSG_MAP(1)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_UP, OnScrollUp)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_DOWN, OnScrollDown)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_PAGE_UP, OnScrollPageUp)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_PAGE_DOWN, OnScrollPageDown)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_TOP, OnScrollTop)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_BOTTOM, OnScrollBottom)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_LEFT, OnScrollLeft)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_RIGHT, OnScrollRight)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_PAGE_LEFT, OnScrollPageLeft)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_PAGE_RIGHT, OnScrollPageRight)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_ALL_LEFT, OnScrollAllLeft)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_ALL_RIGHT, OnScrollAllRight)
    END_MSG_MAP()

    LRESULT OnCreate(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        pT->GetSystemSettings();

        bHandled = FALSE;
        return 1;
    }

    LRESULT OnVScroll(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_VERT, (int)(short)LOWORD(wParam), (int&)m_ptOffset.y, m_sizeAll.cy, m_sizePage.cy, m_sizeLine.cy);
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnHScroll(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));
        pT->DoScroll(SB_HORZ, (int)(short)LOWORD(wParam), (int&)m_ptOffset.x, m_sizeAll.cx, m_sizePage.cx, m_sizeLine.cx);
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnMouseWheel(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));

        int zDelta = (int)GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam);
        int nScrollCode = (m_nWheelLines == WHEEL_PAGESCROLL) ? ((zDelta > 0) ? SB_PAGEUP : SB_PAGEDOWN) : ((zDelta > 0) ? SB_LINEUP : SB_LINEDOWN);
        m_zDelta += zDelta;   // cumulative
        int zTotal = (m_nWheelLines == WHEEL_PAGESCROLL) ? abs(m_zDelta) : abs(m_zDelta) * m_nWheelLines;
        if (m_sizeAll.cy > m_sizeClient.cy)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < zTotal; i += WHEEL_DELTA)
            {
                pT->DoScroll(SB_VERT, nScrollCode, (int&)m_ptOffset.y, m_sizeAll.cy, m_sizePage.cy, m_sizeLine.cy);
                pT->UpdateWindow();
            }
        }
        else if (m_sizeAll.cx > m_sizeClient.cx)   // can't scroll vertically, scroll horizontally
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < zTotal; i += WHEEL_DELTA)
            {
                pT->DoScroll(SB_HORZ, nScrollCode, (int&)m_ptOffset.x, m_sizeAll.cx, m_sizePage.cx, m_sizeLine.cx);
                pT->UpdateWindow();
            }
        }
        m_zDelta %= WHEEL_DELTA;

        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnMouseHWheel(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));

        int zDelta = (int)GET_WHEEL_DELTA_WPARAM(wParam);
        int nScrollCode = (m_nHWheelChars == WHEEL_PAGESCROLL) ? ((zDelta > 0) ? SB_PAGERIGHT : SB_PAGELEFT) : ((zDelta > 0) ? SB_LINERIGHT : SB_LINELEFT);
        m_zHDelta += zDelta;   // cumulative
        int zTotal = (m_nHWheelChars == WHEEL_PAGESCROLL) ? abs(m_zHDelta) : abs(m_zHDelta) * m_nHWheelChars;
        if (m_sizeAll.cx > m_sizeClient.cx)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < zTotal; i += WHEEL_DELTA)
            {
                pT->DoScroll(SB_HORZ, nScrollCode, (int&)m_ptOffset.x, m_sizeAll.cx, m_sizePage.cx, m_sizeLine.cx);
                pT->UpdateWindow();
            }
        }
        m_zHDelta %= WHEEL_DELTA;

        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnSettingChange(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        GetSystemSettings();
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnSize(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM lParam, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        ATLASSERT(::IsWindow(pT->m_hWnd));

        pT->DoSize(GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam));

        bHandled = FALSE;
        return 1;
    }

    // scrolling handlers
    LRESULT OnScrollUp(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        ScrollLineUp();
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnScrollDown(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        ScrollLineDown();
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnScrollPageUp(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        ScrollPageUp();
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnScrollPageDown(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        ScrollPageDown();
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnScrollTop(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        ScrollTop();
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnScrollBottom(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        ScrollBottom();
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnScrollLeft(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        ScrollLineLeft();
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnScrollRight(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        ScrollLineRight();
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnScrollPageLeft(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        ScrollPageLeft();
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnScrollPageRight(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        ScrollPageRight();
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnScrollAllLeft(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        ScrollAllLeft();
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnScrollAllRight(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        ScrollAllRight();
        return 0;
    }

    // Overrideables
    void DoPaint(CDCHandle /*dc*/)
    {
        // must be implemented in a derived class
        ATLASSERT(FALSE);
    }

    // Implementation
    void DoSize(int cx, int cy)
    {
        m_sizeClient.cx = cx;
        m_sizeClient.cy = cy;

        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);

        // block: set horizontal scroll bar
        {
            SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO) };
            si.fMask = SIF_PAGE | SIF_RANGE | SIF_POS;
            si.nMin = 0;
            si.nMax = m_sizeAll.cx - 1;
            if ((m_dwExtendedStyle & SCRL_DISABLENOSCROLLH) != 0)
                si.fMask |= SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL;
            si.nPage = m_sizeClient.cx;
            si.nPos = m_ptOffset.x;
            pT->SetScrollInfo(SB_HORZ, &si, TRUE);
        }

        // block: set vertical scroll bar
        {
            SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO) };
            si.fMask = SIF_PAGE | SIF_RANGE | SIF_POS;
            si.nMin = 0;
            si.nMax = m_sizeAll.cy - 1;
            if ((m_dwExtendedStyle & SCRL_DISABLENOSCROLLV) != 0)
                si.fMask |= SIF_DISABLENOSCROLL;
            si.nPage = m_sizeClient.cy;
            si.nPos = m_ptOffset.y;
            pT->SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &si, TRUE);
        }

        int x = m_ptOffset.x;
        int y = m_ptOffset.y;
        if (pT->AdjustScrollOffset(x, y))
        {
            // Children will be moved in SetScrollOffset, if needed
            pT->ScrollWindowEx(m_ptOffset.x - x, m_ptOffset.y - y, (m_uScrollFlags & ~SCRL_SCROLLCHILDREN));
            SetScrollOffset(x, y, FALSE);
        }
    }

    void DoScroll(int nType, int nScrollCode, int& cxyOffset, int cxySizeAll, int cxySizePage, int cxySizeLine)
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        RECT rect = {};
        pT->GetClientRect(&rect);
        int cxyClient = (nType == SB_VERT) ? rect.bottom : rect.right;
        int cxyMax = cxySizeAll - cxyClient;

        if (cxyMax < 0)   // can't scroll, client area is bigger
            return;

        bool bUpdate = true;
        int cxyScroll = 0;

        switch (nScrollCode)
        {
        case SB_TOP:        // top or all left
            cxyScroll = cxyOffset;
            cxyOffset = 0;
            break;
        case SB_BOTTOM:     // bottom or all right
            cxyScroll = cxyOffset - cxyMax;
            cxyOffset = cxyMax;
            break;
        case SB_LINEUP:     // line up or line left
            if (cxyOffset >= cxySizeLine)
            {
                cxyScroll = cxySizeLine;
                cxyOffset -= cxySizeLine;
            }
            else
            {
                cxyScroll = cxyOffset;
                cxyOffset = 0;
            }
            break;
        case SB_LINEDOWN:   // line down or line right
            if (cxyOffset < cxyMax - cxySizeLine)
            {
                cxyScroll = -cxySizeLine;
                cxyOffset += cxySizeLine;
            }
            else
            {
                cxyScroll = cxyOffset - cxyMax;
                cxyOffset = cxyMax;
            }
            break;
        case SB_PAGEUP:     // page up or page left
            if (cxyOffset >= cxySizePage)
            {
                cxyScroll = cxySizePage;
                cxyOffset -= cxySizePage;
            }
            else
            {
                cxyScroll = cxyOffset;
                cxyOffset = 0;
            }
            break;
        case SB_PAGEDOWN:   // page down or page right
            if (cxyOffset < cxyMax - cxySizePage)
            {
                cxyScroll = -cxySizePage;
                cxyOffset += cxySizePage;
            }
            else
            {
                cxyScroll = cxyOffset - cxyMax;
                cxyOffset = cxyMax;
            }
            break;
        case SB_THUMBTRACK:
            if (IsNoThumbTracking())
                break;
            // else fall through
        case SB_THUMBPOSITION:
        {
            SCROLLINFO si = { sizeof(SCROLLINFO), SIF_TRACKPOS };
            if (pT->GetScrollInfo(nType, &si))
            {
                cxyScroll = cxyOffset - si.nTrackPos;
                cxyOffset = si.nTrackPos;
            }
        }
        break;
        case SB_ENDSCROLL:
        default:
            bUpdate = false;
            break;
        }

        if (bUpdate && (cxyScroll != 0))
        {
            pT->SetScrollPos(nType, cxyOffset, TRUE);
            if (nType == SB_VERT)
                pT->ScrollWindowEx(0, cxyScroll, m_uScrollFlags);
            else
                pT->ScrollWindowEx(cxyScroll, 0, m_uScrollFlags);
        }
    }

    static int CalcLineOrPage(int nVal, int nMax, int nDiv)
    {
        if (nVal == 0)
        {
            nVal = nMax / nDiv;
            if (nVal < 1)
                nVal = 1;
        }
        else if (nVal > nMax)
        {
            nVal = nMax;
        }

        return nVal;
    }

    bool AdjustScrollOffset(int& x, int& y)
    {
        int xOld = x;
        int yOld = y;

        int cxMax = m_sizeAll.cx - m_sizeClient.cx;
        if (x > cxMax)
            x = (cxMax >= 0) ? cxMax : 0;
        else if (x < 0)
            x = 0;

        int cyMax = m_sizeAll.cy - m_sizeClient.cy;
        if (y > cyMax)
            y = (cyMax >= 0) ? cyMax : 0;
        else if (y < 0)
            y = 0;

        return ((x != xOld) || (y != yOld));
    }

    void GetSystemSettings()
    {
        ::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWHEELSCROLLLINES, 0, &m_nWheelLines, 0);

#ifndef SPI_GETWHEELSCROLLCHARS
        const UINT SPI_GETWHEELSCROLLCHARS = 0x006C;
#endif
        ::SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWHEELSCROLLCHARS, 0, &m_nHWheelChars, 0);
    }

    bool IsScrollingChildren() const
    {
        return (m_dwExtendedStyle & SCRL_SCROLLCHILDREN) != 0;
    }

    bool IsErasingBackground() const
    {
        return (m_dwExtendedStyle & SCRL_ERASEBACKGROUND) != 0;
    }

    bool IsNoThumbTracking() const
    {
        return (m_dwExtendedStyle & SCRL_NOTHUMBTRACKING) != 0;
    }

    bool IsSmoothScroll() const
    {
        return (m_dwExtendedStyle & SCRL_SMOOTHSCROLL) != 0;
    }
};

template <class T, class TBase = ATL::CWindow>
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CScrollDialogImpl : public ATL::CDialogImpl<T, TBase>, public CScroller< T >
{
public:
    void InitializeScroll(HWND hWnd)
    {
        T* pT = static_cast<T*>(this);
        pT->GetSystemSettings();

        RECT rect = {};
        this->GetClientRect(&rect);
        pT->DoSize(rect.right, rect.bottom);
    }

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CScrollDialogImpl)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_VSCROLL, CScroller< T >::OnVScroll)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_HSCROLL, CScroller< T >::OnHScroll)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_MOUSEWHEEL, CScroller< T >::OnMouseWheel)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_MOUSEHWHEEL, CScroller< T >::OnMouseHWheel)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_SETTINGCHANGE, CScroller< T >::OnSettingChange)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_SIZE, CScroller< T >::OnSize)
        ALT_MSG_MAP(1)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_UP, CScroller< T >::OnScrollUp)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_DOWN, CScroller< T >::OnScrollDown)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_PAGE_UP, CScroller< T >::OnScrollPageUp)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_PAGE_DOWN, CScroller< T >::OnScrollPageDown)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_TOP, CScroller< T >::OnScrollTop)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_BOTTOM, CScroller< T >::OnScrollBottom)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_LEFT, CScroller< T >::OnScrollLeft)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_RIGHT, CScroller< T >::OnScrollRight)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_PAGE_LEFT, CScroller< T >::OnScrollPageLeft)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_PAGE_RIGHT, CScroller< T >::OnScrollPageRight)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_ALL_LEFT, CScroller< T >::OnScrollAllLeft)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_SCROLL_ALL_RIGHT, CScroller< T >::OnScrollAllRight)
    END_MSG_MAP()
};
```

You can then use it as below (a modeless dialog with enabled vertical and horizontal scrollbars)

```cpp
class CMainDlg : public CScrollDialogImpl<CMainDlg>, public CUpdateUI<CMainDlg>,
        public CMessageFilter, public CIdleHandler
{
public:
    enum { IDD = IDD_MAINDLG };

    virtual BOOL PreTranslateMessage(MSG* pMsg)
    {
        return CWindow::IsDialogMessage(pMsg);
    }

    virtual BOOL OnIdle()
    {
        UIUpdateChildWindows();
        return FALSE;
    }

    BEGIN_UPDATE_UI_MAP(CMainDlg)
    END_UPDATE_UI_MAP()

    BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMainDlg)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_INITDIALOG, OnInitDialog)
        MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_DESTROY, OnDestroy)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(ID_APP_ABOUT, OnAppAbout)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(IDOK, OnOK)
        COMMAND_ID_HANDLER(IDCANCEL, OnCancel)

        CHAIN_MSG_MAP(CScrollDialogImpl<CMainDlg>);
    END_MSG_MAP()

    LRESULT OnInitDialog(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        this->InitializeScroll(m_hWnd);

        RECT rect = {};
        this->GetClientRect(&rect);

        SetScrollSize(rect.right + 200, rect.bottom + 200);

        // center the dialog on the screen
        CenterWindow();

        // set icons
        HICON hIcon = AtlLoadIconImage(IDR_MAINFRAME, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR, 
            ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON), ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON));
        SetIcon(hIcon, TRUE);
        HICON hIconSmall = AtlLoadIconImage(IDR_MAINFRAME, LR_DEFAULTCOLOR, 
            ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSMICON), ::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSMICON));
        SetIcon(hIconSmall, FALSE);

        // register object for message filtering and idle updates
        CMessageLoop* pLoop = _Module.GetMessageLoop();
        ATLASSERT(pLoop != NULL);
        pLoop->AddMessageFilter(this);
        pLoop->AddIdleHandler(this);

        UIAddChildWindowContainer(m_hWnd);

        return TRUE;
    }

    LRESULT OnDestroy(UINT /*uMsg*/, WPARAM /*wParam*/, LPARAM /*lParam*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        // unregister message filtering and idle updates
        CMessageLoop* pLoop = _Module.GetMessageLoop();
        ATLASSERT(pLoop != NULL);
        pLoop->RemoveMessageFilter(this);
        pLoop->RemoveIdleHandler(this);

        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnAppAbout(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD /*wID*/, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        CAboutDlg dlg;
        dlg.DoModal();
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnOK(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD wID, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        // TODO: Add validation code 
        CloseDialog(wID);
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnCancel(WORD /*wNotifyCode*/, WORD wID, HWND /*hWndCtl*/, BOOL& /*bHandled*/)
    {
        CloseDialog(wID);
        return 0;
    }

    void CloseDialog(int nVal)
    {
        DestroyWindow();
        ::PostQuitMessage(nVal);
    }
};
```